# Yii2: add extra attributes to the script using Asset Manager

Tags: yii2

```
<script async src="https://usocial.pro/usocial/usocial.js?v=6.1.4" data-script="usocial" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

How to include in appAsset:

1. async
   and
2. data-script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the script inside your `public $js` array as follows for using inside the `AppAsset`

```
public $js = [
    [
     'https://usocial.pro/usocial/usocial.js?v=6.1.4', 
     'async' => 'async',
     'data'=>['script'=>'usocial']
    ]
];
```

> Note: if you want the async option to be turned on for all scripts
>   that are loaded via Assets then you can use the `public $jsOptions`
>   too

```
public $jsOptions = [
    'async' => 'async',
];
```